# How do I get Nothingness after buying Quantum CPU? (Succubox)

Tags: succubox

Lootboxes just give "everything" now. Is there any other way to get nothingness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a look at the source you'll notice that the "everything" from quantum boxes includes nothingness at the same rate (probability) as opening regular boxes. You'll have plenty of nothingness once you have more workers.